# How to change borders on hover-menu?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, border

I have given a right-border (1px solid #000) to menu1 here and a left-border to menu2.

The problem is that that way the dropdown menu takes on the attributes of the main menu and has only a right border.

How can I 
1) have no border at all on the dropdown menu? 
2) have the dropdown menu with borders? (top, left, right and bottom)

Here is the menu: http://jsbin.com/tifuhute/30/

Comment: It has a border ... change color to something like #f00 and you will see

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to change the border functionality. I would suggest you to use the addclass function and removeclass function in jQuery.

Learn how to use them below:

http://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/html_addclass.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_removeclass.asp

Answer (score 0):

1: Since it appears the links are the ones with the border, you can add this css rule to the menu1 so that the links in the dropdown menus do not have the border:

```
.menu1 ul a{
      border: none;
}
```

2: I'm not sure what you want. If you want the whole dropdown menu with borders, you can add this css rule, for example:

```
.menu1 ul{
      border: 1px black solid;
}
```

I tried these css rules and they appear to be working fine